# rails - assets are still served even if commented in app.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to use react-bootstrap but I'm struggling with the following error:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded

I read that it has something to do with the fact that ***react is referenced multiple times*** and I'm trying to figure out why and where I did this mistake.

***So, in order to solve this, I tried uncommenting some lines in application.js***, maybe there is the problem (I thought some lines have imported inside react - but I think the scope would be only that file so it wouldn't matter anyway)

This is my application.js

```
//#= require jquery
//#= require bootstrap-sprockets
//#= require underscore
//#= require backbone
//#= require backbone_rails_sync
//#= require backbone_datalink
//#= require react
//#= require react_ujs
//#= require react_bootstrap
//= require utils
//= require components
```

components.js

```
//#= require underscore
//#= require backbone
//#= require react-server
//= require components/admin/general
//#= require components/admin/settings
```

Initially they were all uncommented, but now I commented some of them. I ran

```
rake assets:clean
rake assets:precompile
```

once and the second only rake assets:clean but Rails is still serving old assets. Why?

I changed the following inside development.rb

```
config.assets.digest = false
config.assets.debug = true
```

and inside my console when I start rails server and navigate to some path, it references all my scripts, which I do not want..

In the following ***application.js***, react is commented so any code that references React inside components **SHOULD NOT WORK**, but **IT WORKS**.

How to tell Rails to *reset assets mentioned in application.js*?

Answer (score 0):

Well..nevermind

I found out that comment is done by removing the equal sign, not adding #